# propagate excel changes back to sql server table

Tags: excel

So I'm in Excel and I connected to my SQL Server Table.

I updated a couple columns in Excel.

```
column1,column2
updated1, updated2
updated3, updated3
```

Is there a way in the VBA Immediate Window to run an update statement to propagate the changes back to SQL? Or any other simple way welcomed too.

Comment: You need to at least have some kind of primary key in your existing data to identify the rows that have been updated. Does your source table have a primary key, and is it in your Excel dataset? One simple way is to use an Excel string formula to build an UPDATE statement on each row then copy/paste that into SSMS and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of SQL Server, it may be better to link to the Excel file and execute a stored procedure to import the data via a SQL statement. You can push the data from Excel but need the code for connecting to the SQL server, then the SQL to execute the append or update query.

You can invoke the code from the immediate window but need a couple of functions in Excel to pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to transfer the changes in Excel back to SQL Server from time to time, an easy way is to copy and paste the data back to your SQL Server table.

1. Select and copy the cells in Excel that you would like to paste into your SQL Server table.
2. Right-click your table in Management Studio and select 'Edit top 200 Rows'.
3. In the bottom-row, click on the star in the the left-side column header to select the whole row.
4. Now click Ctrl-V to paste your Excel data into your SQL Server table.

Tip: If you have an ID column with Identity (auto incrementing): Clear the Id column in Excel, but keep it selected and SQL Server will generate new IDs when you paste the rows.

If you need to update the SQL Server table from Excel on a regular basis, you can check out an Excel to SQL Server tool I am developing: [www.sqlspreads.com](http://www.sqlspreads.com)